# how to call procedure inside package using function

Tags: plsql

I have created function for the condition number greater than 0 and less than 20. I want to call the variable declared in function in procedure using package. when i give value 5 in function means in procedure it should insert the values for 5 times in table. how to achieve this?

```
create or replace package Body test2
as

function f1(no number) return number
is

var number;

Begin 
  
   if no>0 and no<20 Then
     var :=no;
     return 0;
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('The input is not matched with the requirement');
      return 1;
    end if;
   
end;

procedure p1
is

number1 number;

begin
  

for number1 in 1..var
  loop
    insert into val_insert(value,cur_date) values('ramji',TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
  end loop;
end;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare a variable in the package body (outside of all procedures and functions) to share that value between the function and the procedure. Just move the `var: number;` line before the `function` line.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a variable declared in the function is the function itself - it is not visible outside the function. You *could* create a global variable at package level and reference that in the function but honestly, that isn't very good practice. The goal of a function is to wrap a specific piece of functionality and return something. By assigning a globally accessible variable in the function the code becomes a lot more messy and unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to achieve this, but it depends on what you want. Because you know the value (since it's passed to f1), then you can pass it as a parameter to p1. There is no reason to do it in two separate steps. If you want to somehow store it for a later call, then you will need a table for that. You can use a sort of a "global" variable (rather a public variable stored in the package), but it is not persistent. It will only last for that session.

The real question is what you want to really achieve, because to me, there seems to be a problem in the overall code design. It doesn't make sense that you know what param to send to f1, but you don't know it for p1, when it's supposed to be the same one.

If you want the simplest approach, I would move everything in p1 and make the valdiation an `OUT` parameter. This should cover everything and remove the whole redundant code and remove any dependencies.

Here is an example:

```
create or replace package test2 as
    procedure p1 (iterations in number, execution_result out number, error_message out nocopy varchar2);
end test2;
/

create or replace package body test2 as
procedure p1 (iterations in number, execution_result out number, error_message out nocopy varchar2)
is
begin
    if (iterations between 0 and 20) then
        execution_result := 0;
    else
        error_message := 'The input is not matched with the requirement';
        execution_result := 1;
        return;
    end if;

    for i in 1..iterations
    loop
        insert into val_insert(value,cur_date) values('ramji',sysdate);
        commit;
    end loop;
exception
    when others then
        execution_result := 2;
        error_message := sqlerrm;
        rollback;
end p1;
end test2;
/

declare
    iterations number := 5;
    execution_result number;
    error_message varchar2(4000);
begin
    test2.p1(iterations, execution_result, error_message);
    
    if (execution_result <> 0) then
        dbms_output.put_line('Error type: ' || execution_result);
        dbms_output.put_line('Error: ' || error_message);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Executed successfully');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Now, for some caveats:

Note that iterators don't need to be declared as variables. It's enough to be declared as inline in PL/SQL. That's why I removed the `number1` declaration. Also note that you can use `BETWEEN` so no need for that ugly `(a > 0 and a < 20)`.

Furthermore, even if it's just a test, don't use `dbms_output.put_line` inside code. Use string variables, export them outside the procedure or function and display them in the entry point.

I am also curious what this code does: `TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`. sysdate is of type DATE. TO_DATE turns a date-literal into a date. This makes no sense as you're turning a date into a date which is pointless. I also don't understand why you want to insert the current date and time when SQL has a native implementation of `DEFAULT VALUES` for tables which require zero code. You are also inserting "ramji" in that column for every record. What's the point of a static value that is always the same in every record?

Also your code has no exception handling, no `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. I for one have no clue what it should do, because from what I see, it won't execute anything. And if you say that you COMMIT `externally`, how are you handling `ROLLBACK`s?

My advice is that you start from zero, because looking at this, it seems you googled what you needed and just added code from all over the place in the hopes that it will do what you want it to do.

You need a more dedicated approach for this. You should start first start with basic SQL. After you master that (and not before), you can start learning some PL/SQL and then look up some code design tutorials or articles (I don't mean it in a bad way, even if it sounds like that), while also studying PL/SQL. There are a lot of areas where improvements can result in much simpler and more efficient code. Not to mention there are some best practices that are being violated in the above code, even if it is just an example.

It seems there are some things that you think they do something, but they don't do what you think. For instance, `TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')` won't insert dates and arrange them into european format separated by backslashes. You need to look up NLS.